# Evaluate calculations on label

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations

I would like to display the evaluation of data on node instead display the values. What I mean is instead `\x + 3*\y` evaluate to `0 + 3*0` it should display `0`, the result of calculation. How to do that?

```
\documentclass [12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=-1cm]{every node/.style={font=\scriptsize}}
\draw [step=.1cm,very thin,black!10] (0,0) grid (6,6);
\draw [step=2cm,thin,black!50] (0,0) grid (6,6);
\draw [very thick,black] (0,0) rectangle (6,6);
\draw [->,very thick] (0,0) --  (6.5,0) node[below] {$X$};
\draw [->,very thick] (0,0) --  (0,6.5) node[right] {$Z$};

    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,2} {
        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,2} {
            \node (node) [label={[yshift=-.6cm, xshift=.3cm]:\x + 3*\y}] at (2*\x,2*\y) {};
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would evaluate it as part of the loop. For example,

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=-1cm]{every node/.style={font=\scriptsize}}
  \draw [step=.1cm,very thin,black!10] (0,0) grid (6,6);
  \draw [step=2cm,thin,black!50] (0,0) grid (6,6);
  \draw [very thick,black] (0,0) rectangle (6,6);
  \draw [->,very thick] (0,0) --  (6.5,0) node[below] {$X$};
  \draw [->,very thick] (0,0) --  (0,6.5) node[right] {$Z$};

  \foreach \x in {0,1,...,2} {
    \foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \z using {int(\x+3*\y)}] in {0,1,...,2} {
      \node (node) [label={[yshift=-.6cm, xshift=.3cm]:\z}] at (2*\x,2*\y) {};
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: results in picture]

Alternatively, you could calculate `\z` within the loop. For example,

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\z{int(\x+3*\y)}
```

before typesetting the `\node` would effectively do the same thing.

## EDIT [Response to [follow-up](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435901/evaluate-calculations-on-label/435903?noredirect=1#comment1093257_435903)]

You could just put the labels inside the nodes and set the anchor as you wish, rather than messing around with shifts. For example,

```
\node  [anchor=north west] at (2*\x,2*\y) {\z};
```

produces

[image: anchored labelling nodes]

Answer (score 7):

You can evaluate expressions with the suitable keys in a for loop. Hence if you change your code to

```
    \foreach \y[evaluate={\yi=int(\x + 3*\y);}] in {0,1,...,2} {
        \node (node) [label={[yshift=-.6cm, xshift=.3cm]:\yi}] at (2*\x,2*\y) {};
```

Here `int` is needed to return integers instead of 1.0, 2.0... etc.

Comment: Hello, do you know where the documentation is for this particular form of `evaluate = {...}` that you used without loading the `math` library *(where it seems to me it's defined)*?